# Non-recursive find with lxml builder

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I find in Python 2.7 that I cannot do a non-recursive `bs4.BeautifulSoup.find_all` if I use the `lxml` builder.

Take the following example HTML snippet:

```
<p> <b> Cats </b> are interesting creatures </p>

<p> <b> Dogs </b> are cool too </p>

<div>
<p> <b> Penguins </b> are pretty neat, but they're inside a div </p>
</div>

<p> <b> Llamas </b> don't live in New York </p>
```

Say I want to find all `p` elements that are direct children. I do a non-recursive `find_all` with `find_all("p", recursive=False)`.

In order to test this, I set the above HTML snippet in a variable called `html`. Then, I created two `BeautifulSoup` instances, `a` and `b`:

```
a = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
```

They both perform correctly when using `find_all` normally:

```
>>> a.find_all("p")
[<p> <b> Cats </b> are interesting creatures </p>, <p> <b> Dogs </b> are cool too </p>, <p> <b> Penguins </b> are pretty neat, but they're inside a div </p>, <p> <b> Llamas </b> don't live in New York </p>]
>>> b.find_all("p")
[<p> <b> Cats </b> are interesting creatures </p>, <p> <b> Dogs </b> are cool too </p>, <p> <b> Penguins </b> are pretty neat, but they're inside a div </p>, <p> <b> Llamas </b> don't live in New York </p>]
```

but if I turn off recursive finding, only `a` works. `b` returns an empty list:

```
>>> a.find_all("p", recursive=False)
[<p> <b> Cats </b> are interesting creatures </p>, <p> <b> Dogs </b> are cool too </p>, <p> <b> Llamas </b> don't live in New York </p>]
>>> b.find_all("p", recursive=False)
[]
```

Why is this? Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Does the `lxml` builder support non-recursive `find_all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `lxml` parser would put your HTML code into `html/body` if it is not present:

```
>>> b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
>>> print(b)
<html><body><p> <b> Cats </b> are interesting creatures </p>
<p> <b> Dogs </b> are cool too </p>
<div>
<p> <b> Penguins </b> are pretty neat, but they're inside a div </p>
</div>
<p> <b> Llamas </b> don't live in New York </p>
</body></html>
```

And, hence, the `find_all()` in non-recursive mode would try to find elements inside `html` element, which has an only `body` child:

```
>>> print(b.find_all("p", recursive=False))
[]
>>> print(b.body.find_all("p", recursive=False))
[<p> <b> Cats </b> are interesting creatures </p>, <p> <b> Dogs </b> are cool too </p>, <p> <b> Llamas </b> don't live in New York </p>]
```

Comment: This seems like an inconsistency to me, why should different parsers behave differently in this way?

Comment: @LukeTaylor it could be confusing, I agree. There is some information about that in [Differences between parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) documentation paragraph. It all comes down to different parsers making a non-well-formed HTML a valid one - they just all do it differently.